# Pulling Files from Mongo DB into CSV using python

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I am new to python and I was trying to pull the data from mongodb using python and import it into a csv file.Can some one tell me from where should I start.

I am so new to both the technologies,But trying to learn.

If someone could help me it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `pymongo`: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html

The are also some great introductory videos to MongoDB on youtube demonstrating basic CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete) and working in the mongo shell, which is the core interface to MongoDB.

Comment: Thankyou.I was using RoboMongo as my client interface for Mongo DB.